# Size of circular list in C++ using Double Pointer

Tags: linked-list, nodes, circular-list

The function in resulting in an infinite loop. It is not able to return the number of nodes. Where am I going wrong?

```
    int Count(struct node **head)
  {

     printf("entered");
     struct node **temp;
     int count = 0;
     temp = &((*head)->next);
     while ((&(*temp)->next) != head)
     {
         printf("entered");
         temp = &((*temp)->next);
         count++;
     }
 return count;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the provide source code, the while-condition is referring to addresses of pointers (where the pointer is stored) and the `struct node **head` is pointing to a static location in the `main()` but `(&(*temp)->next)` is pointing to the allocated of the last item.

> To compare items in a linked-list, you should compare pointers `struct
>   node *` instead of addresses of pointers `struct node **`.
>
> In the `Count()` function, because the `*head` exists (not compared to
>   NULL), the counter `count` should start from 1 and to count all items in the circular-list, you should start by `temp = &(*head);` instead of the next item `temp = &((*head)->next);`.

Here after is a ["Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NODE_MAX (5)

struct node {
   struct node *next;
};

int Count(struct node **head)
{
    printf("entered");
    struct node **temp;
    int count = 1; // at least the '*head' node exists
    temp = &(*head);// &((*head)->next);
    while (((*temp)->next) != *head) // use '*head'
    {
        printf("entered");
        temp = &((*temp)->next);
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    struct node array[NODE_MAX];
    struct node *head, *temp;

    head = &(array[0]);
    temp = head;
    for(int i=1;i<NODE_MAX;i++) {
        temp->next = &(array[i]);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = &(array[0]);

    printf("\nCount = %d\n",Count(&head));

    system("pause");
    return (0);
}
```

It would be more simple to manage linked-list at pointers level like the following example:

```
int Count2(struct node **head)
{
    printf("entered");
    struct node *temp;
    int count = 1;
    temp = (*head); // pointers to the first
    while (temp->next != *head) // direct pointer comparison
    {
        printf("entered");
        temp = temp->next; // natural linked-list exploration
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```